# ¿Por qué obtengo este error en python con tkinter?

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de hacer una calculadora y a la hora de imprimir el número por pantalla hago click y no aparece. Esto es lo que tengo programado de código:

```
from tkinter import *
import os

raiz = Tk()
miFrame = Frame(raiz)

# empaquetamos el frame
miFrame.pack()

#root
raiz.title('Calculadora')

# pantalla
pantalla = Entry(miFrame)
pantalla.grid(row=1,column=1, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=4)
pantalla.config(background='black', fg='#03f943', justify='right')

#------------------------------------------------------------------------

numeroPantalla = StringVar()
pantalla = Entry(miFrame, textvariable=numeroPantalla)

# Pulsaciones teclado
def numeroPulsado():
    numeroPantalla.set('7')
    

# Botones fila 1
boton7 = Button(miFrame, text='7', width=3, command=numeroPulsado)
boton7.grid(row=2, column=1)
boton8 = Button(miFrame, text='8', width=3)
boton8.grid(row=2, column=2)
boton9 = Button(miFrame, text='9', width=3)
boton9.grid(row=2, column=3)
botonDiv = Button(miFrame, text='/', width=3)
botonDiv.grid(row=2, column=4)
```

Cómo veis estoy tratando de imprimir el número 7 pero por cualquier circunstancia no me está dejando hacerlo. Estoy usando la función numeroPulsado para poder hacerlo. ¿Sabéis dónde puede estar el problema?

Comment: El Entry "pantalla" no está mostrandose por que no lo ubicaste en ningún lado. Tenes que usar grid, place o pack y será visible. Haciendo eso, tu código deberia de funcionar bien.

Comment: El grid lo tengo programado más abajo, con pantalla.grid() y todos los parámetros

Comment: Que raro... Entonces deberia funcionar. En ese caso, el error debe de estar en el código original. No te pediré ese código, pero si publicas un [emcv](/help/minimal-reproducible-example), podré identificar mejor el error y hacer las pruebas necesarias.

Comment: No se a qué te refieres con el código original. Ese es el único código que tengo.

Comment: A veces, el código en la pregunta no es el mismo que el que esta en la computadora del que pregunta. A tu código publicado le falta el grid del entry "pantalla" y el mainloop. Pero dices que el grid está presente. Es una contradiccion. Por eso te pedi un mcve, para ver que pasa realmente.

Comment: Un segundo, acabo de entender que está pasando. Ya te doy una respuesta.

Comment: Vale gracias @DanteS. !!

Comment: @FranciscoJavier Un stringvar no se cambia de valor usando variables globales. Si no que se modifica el objeto "in-place". No se asigna nada a ninguna variable global al tratar de modificar un StringVar.

Comment: !Es posible que funcione pero no se vea porque el fondo es igual al color de la fuente! ja ja

Comment: o que creas dos veces el objeto pantalla y la ultima no tiene tamaño

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explicación

Estás creando dos entrys pantalla.

El primero es este:

```
pantalla = Entry(miFrame)
pantalla.grid(row=1,column=1, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=4)
pantalla.config(background='black', fg='#03f943', justify='right')
```

El cual ubicas, configuras y todo. Este entry es el que vez cuando ejecutas tu script.
Peeero, NO tiene asociado la variable `numeroPantalla`.

Luego, sobreescribes la variable pantalla con la siguiente linea:

```
pantalla = Entry(miFrame, textvariable=numeroPantalla)
```

Este nuevo entry, no es visible por que no usaste ningún administrador de geometría sobre el.
Este entry invisible tiene asociado a `numeroPantalla`.

> En resumen, tenés un entry visible que no está asociado a ninguna
> variable y otro entry invisible que tiene asociado la variable.

Entonces, cuando cambias el valor del StringVar, se actualiza el texto del Entry invisible.

#### Solución

Simplemente, creamos solo un entry pantalla y le asociamos a ese mismo el StringVar.

```
from tkinter import *
import os

raiz = Tk()
miFrame = Frame(raiz)

# empaquetamos el frame
miFrame.pack()

#root
raiz.title('Calculadora')

"Cambio aquí"
# pantalla
numeroPantalla = StringVar()

pantalla = Entry(miFrame, textvariable=numeroPantalla)
pantalla.grid(row=1,column=1, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=4)
pantalla.config(background='black', fg='#03f943', justify='right')

#------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Pulsaciones teclado
def numeroPulsado():
    numeroPantalla.set('7')
    

# Botones fila 1
boton7 = Button(miFrame, text='7', width=3, command=numeroPulsado)
boton7.grid(row=2, column=1)
boton8 = Button(miFrame, text='8', width=3)
boton8.grid(row=2, column=2)
boton9 = Button(miFrame, text='9', width=3)
boton9.grid(row=2, column=3)
botonDiv = Button(miFrame, text='/', width=3)
botonDiv.grid(row=2, column=4)
```

Comment: Perfecto, funciona. Muchas gracias!